# Sum the Quantity which holds the same ID c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

There is an ASP.NET MVC application with an Order Data table and the table contains the order part ID and the Order Qty.

So somehow the previous developer set the Order Qty as string type.

Now for a report, I want to get a sum of the Qty according to the same Part Id's and show it, but it won't work.

Can you help me with this?

```
foreach(var item in rData) {
  try {
    if (db.OrderTable.Any(u => u.PartNo_Id == item.Id)) {

      item.TotalOrderQty = db.OrderTable.Where(x => x.PartNo_Id == item.Id).Sum(x => x.OrderQty);
    }

  } catch (Exception ex) {

    throw ex;
  }

}
```

the error is `cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'long'` on the `(x=>x.OrderQty)`

Comment: You'll need to convert the `x.OrderQty` to a number before LINQ can sum it up for you, something like [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-6.0), or better yet [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0) to handle non numbers gracefully. You'll maybe have to re-write your query to explicitly switch to client side evaluation depending on whether or not an exception gets thrown about that issue

Comment: @MindSwipe I tried both ``Convert.ToInt32`` and ``int.parse`` but still get the same message

Comment: Insert a `.Select(x => x.OrderQty).ToList()` after the `.Where`, that will make the database return a list of all the OrderQty. That should allow you to convert the values to numbers on the client. Not as efficient as letting the database do it, but I'm not sure if Convert.ToInt32 can be traslated to SQL.

Comment: @MindSwipe Thanks for the advice. The issue was at the ``rData`` list. I just noted it, and then used ``int.Parse`` and worked.

Comment: @DevBeginner this isn't ASP.NET code. Are you using EF or EF Core? It matters. You'll have to get the ORM to generate SQL that casts the string to a number. Of course the *real* solution is to just fix the database field. What are you going to do if someone stores `potato` in there?

Comment: @DevBeginner have you tried using `.Sum(x => int.Parse(x.OrderQty))` or `.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.OrderQty))` ? Your ORM (which one?) would probably translate this to `SUM(cast(OrderQty as INT))`. If that fails, someone probably *did* store `potato` in there. You'll have to find and fix the dirty data. In SQL you could ignore it with eg `WHERE ISNUMERIC(OrderQty)=1` but you'll probably generate the wrong sums this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `db` object is an OR-Mapper to a real database you are making a lot of queries which could be optimized, cause for every item in your list you ask at first, if data is available and at second trying to query these informations. It would be more effective to request the data in one shot (if it is not millions of lines) and compute the sums on the client side.

Maybe this sketch can help you:

```
// Define matching Ids to read from database
var idsToSearch = rData.Select(item => item.Id);

var matchingOrders = db.OrderTable
    // Define criteria, which data has to be fetch.
    .Join(idsToSearch, order => order.PartNo_Id, id => id, (order, id) => order)
    // Prepare data on the server side to be already being grouped.
    .GroupBy(order => order.PartNo_Id)
    // Load data from the server to the client
    .AsEnumerable()
    // Parse and summarize the data on the client side.
    .Select(group => (group.Key, group.SelectMany(order => int.Parse(order.OrderQty).Sum())
    .ToList();
```

Depending on your model it could make sense to strip down the really needed data between the `.Join()` and the `.GroupBy()` call if the table holds a lot of (in this request unneeded) columns. Also be aware, that this code is not tested and maybe contains some stupid typo or similar, but it should give you a good starting point on how to tackle your problem.

#### Update (convert string to int on server side)

Thanks to Panagiotis comment, EF supports conversion methods and translates them to the corresponding SQL methods. Due to this fact, everything could be done on the server side. This could probably look something like this:

```
var matchingOrders = db.OrderTable
    .Join(idsToSearch, order => order.PartNo_Id, id => id, (order, id) => order)
    .GroupBy(order => order.PartNo_Id)
    .Select(group => (group.Key, group.SelectMany(order => Convert.ToInt32(order.OrderQty).Sum())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This only moves the problem to the client. EF Core can convert values, and [Convert.Int32 maps to CONVERT(int,..)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions#conversion-functions). Either the column contains dirty data or the database provider doesn't support conversions. In any case this would only cover up the real problem

Comment: I wasn't sure (cause never used it) that EF support type conversion methods out-of-the-box. That's the reason for the movement to the client side. But you're right. Whatever can be done on the server side should be done their.